# Using Armadillo C++ library in Swift 5

Tags: c++, swift, uibezierpath, armadillo, dylib

I'm trying to use **Armadillo** C++ library in my swift code to create sinusoidal curved arrow. Earlier it worked well with Objective C. But when I'm trying to do the same implementation in Swift, it's showing `'armadillo' file not found` error.

I've downloaded the file from https://github.com/gadomski/armadillo/tree/master/branch-5.600/include path and copied both armadillo_bits folder and armadillo file into the project.

I've created a Objective C++ Wrapper around the C++ class too.

Objective C++ Wrapper **DrawSinusoidal.h** file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DrawSinusoidal : NSObject

+(NSArray *)bezierPathsForPoints:(NSArray *)points;
```

Objective C++ Wrapper **DrawSinusoidal.mm** file

```
#import "DrawSinusoidal.h"
#import "DrawSinusoidalMath.h"

@implementation DrawSinusoidal

+(NSArray *)bezierPathsForPoints:(NSArray *)points {
 ...
}
```

C++ file - **DrawSinusoidalMath.h**

```
#include "armadillo"

std::vector<std::vector<arma::vec2>> bezierPathsForPoints(const std::vector<arma::vec2> &points);
```

C++ file - **DrawSinusoidalMath.cpp** file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DrawSinusoidalMath.h"

using namespace arma;

std::vector<arma::vec2> bezierPathsForPoints(const arma::mat &tValues, const std::vector<arma::vec2> &points)
{
... 
...
 return points
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution to it. Sharing the steps which I followed.

- We need to install the pre-built Armadillo packages to macOS which can be installed via [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/?search=armadillo&search_by=name) or [HomeBrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/armadillo)
- I installed using HomeBrew.

`$ brew install armadillo`

Once it is completed, please keep a note on the installed path from the last line.
[image]

In my machine, it is installed on path `/usr/local/Cellar/armadillo/10.5.1`

- Next, we need to provide the Header Search Paths.
  Headers are available in below location, so just copy the path and paste in Xcode.

`/usr/local/Cellar/armadillo/10.5.1/include/armadillo_bits`

[image]

- Next, we need to link the `libarmadillo.dylib` library that is available in the installed path to the sdk path in the Xcode. Open terminal and type following command.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/armadillo/10.5.1/lib/libarmadillo.dylib /Applications/Xcode_12.4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/usr/lib/libarmadillo.dylib
```

- Once done, now you can go to `Targets > Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries`
  You should see `libarmadillo.dylib`
  Select and add it to your project.

[image]

- Final step.. Copy `armadillo` text file and `armadillo_bits` folder, from below path to the project.
  `/usr/local/Cellar/armadillo/10.5.1/include`
  [image]

That's it.. The setup is over and you can use the Armadillo library in C++ files inside Objective-C/Swift projects.